# Da Vinci Resolve Free

Tags: video-editor

I hope this post finds you all well.

I have a short video clip (.mp4) and I wish to trim the last 5-6 seconds of it.

I tried the Ripple Cut approach and it works on trimming from the start of a clip to a place in the middle but not from near the end to the very end.

Would the Razor function work better?

Can you pls. share the exact steps?

I place the Playhead exactly where I wish to start trimming and then press the Razor Blade (icon) to make that Razor Blade turn red? Then….?

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 2):

Ripple Cut works by shuffling everything to the right of your cut leftward until it butts against your existing timeline.

If all you need to do is truncate the end of your video, just hover over the end of the clip in the timeline. The cursor will turn into a trim tool - either double-sided or single, as you slide the cursor slightly left. The double-sided cursor will, in effect, 'slide' your edit point without changing the timing of the overall timeline. The single razor will leave a gap if you shorten your clip. If you are only truncating a single clip, it doesn't matter in practise which you use, both will do the same thing in this instance.

All you need to do is grab this & drag left.

[image]
<sub>Image enlarged to make the tool easier to see.</sub>